# Map Polygon Tooltip: How to combine spatial data and fields

Tags: reporting-services

I am creating an SSRS Report in Visual Studio, and showing a map using the Map tool.

I have some spatial data from a US map shape file which has a field called

```
#STATENAME
```

and I have a dataset containing a field called

```
Count
```

I can choose to show either in the polygon tooltip, but how do I combine these?
What I want to see in the tooltip is:

```
Arizona - 12345
```

Every combination I've tried so far causes an error - for example (1 of many variations I've tried):

```
=(#STATENAME & " - " & Fields!Count.Value)
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you not reference `Fields!STATENAME.Value`?

Comment: No, STATENAME isn't a field in the dataset....

Comment: Then how are you linking your data to the polygon?

Comment: By using the 2-letter state abbreviation (e.g. WA) in field STUSPS in the map linked to a similar field in the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not recommended by Microsoft, but you *can* use both at the same time.  Ideally you would simply add the full State names to your dataset.

`="#STATENAME" & " - " & Fields!Count.Value`